# Context menu click/open event with Atom Shell/Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to capture the click even on a tray icon click with a context menu on OSX, but according to the docs this is disabled in OSX for some reason:

```
Platform limitations:

On OS X clicked event will be ignored if the tray icon has context menu.
```

I've wondering if there is another way to know when a tray icon with a context menu is interacted with?

Relavent code:

```
var app = require('app');
var path = require('path')
var Menu = require('menu');
var MenuItem = require('menu-item');
var Tray = require('tray');

var appIcon = null;
var menu = null;
app.on('ready', function(){
  appIcon = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'images/icon.png'));

  appIcon.on('clicked', function(event, bounds) {
      console.log('clicked');
  });

  menu = new Menu();

  menu.append(new MenuItem({ label: 'Quit', id: 'quit', click: function() { app.quit(); } }));
  appIcon.setContextMenu(menu);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it works on OS X (10.11.4).

Please check. main.js:

```
// Load in dependencies
var app = require('app');
var Tray = require('tray');

// When the Electron has loaded
app.on('ready', function onready () {
  // Log to the console to verify logging works
  console.log('Hello World!');

  // Create a tray
  var tray = new Tray(__dirname + '/icon.png');

  // When the tray icon is clicked, log to our console
  tray.on('click', function handleClicked () {
    console.log('Tray clicked');
  });
});
```

Run:

```
electron main.js
```